# How to make ObservableBooleanValue with two arguments in Java?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, boolean-logic

I want to add second argument to when() condition for ObservableBooleanValue. In case when there is only one argument
it`s working correctly. Problem in that line:

```
game.winnerProperty().isEqualTo(Square.State.EMPTY) || (GameTimer::isTimeOver==true)
```

This is ok:

```
game.winnerProperty().isEqualTo(Square.State.EMPTY) //This is BooleanBinding
```

Code:

```
playerLabel.textProperty().bind(
    Bindings.when(
        game.gameOverProperty().not()
    )
        .then("Actual Player: ")
        .otherwise(
            Bindings.when(
                game.winnerProperty().isEqualTo(Square.State.EMPTY) || (GameTimer::isTimeOver==true)
            )
                .then("Draw")
                .otherwise("Winner: ")
        )
);
```

How to add second argument which type is boolean?

Comment: `(GameTimer::isTimeOver==true)`??? Why would a method reference be equal to a `boolean` and what would be the functional interface this would be used for???

Comment: Is this `isTimeOver` also a property? Or just a field?

Comment: @JornVernee It would have to be a method, since that is the syntax for a method reference: though it makes absolutely no sense to have a method reference there.

Comment: @James_D I don't think that is the intent here. It looks similar to static field access in C++, so maybe OP is confused with that. That's why I asked.

Comment: Naming a field as a verb would not exactly be intuitive either. Occam's razor suggests going with the minimum number of errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
game.winnerProperty().isEqualTo(Square.State.EMPTY).or(/* whatever you actually mean here */);
```

The argument to `or` here needs to be another `ObservableBooleanValue` (e.g. a `BooleanProperty`): I don't really know what is intended by the method reference you currently have.

Comment: game.winnerProperty().isEqualTo(Square.State.EMPTY).or(GameTimer::isTimeOver==true)
isTimeOver is set to TRUE when time is over. How to change isTimeOver to boolean type?

Comment: @user3455638 No-one except you knows what you mean by `GameTimer::isTimeOver`.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's convenient to combine multiple bindings.

However this can lead to complex code that is hard to understand/maintain. It would be easier to use `Bindings.createStringBinding` and add the proper dependencies:

```
playerLabel.textProperty().bind(
    Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
            if (game.isGameOver()) {
                 return Square.State.EMPTY.equals(game.getWinner()) || gameTimer.isTimeOver()
                              ? "Draw"
                              : "Winner: ";
            } else {
                 return "Actual Player: ";
            }
        },
        game.gameOverProperty(),
        game.winnerProperty(),
        gameTimer.timeOverProperty()));
```